# Error: :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: java, android, gradle

I decided to integrate appodeal into the application, did everything according to the instructions, but the result is still the same:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator$7.class

I googled this question, but I still could not find a solution.
Here is gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.successdev.bookwindev.bookwin"
        vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = ['hdpi', 'xxhdpi']
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile project(':caldroidcustom')
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.6'

    compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

P.S Sorry for my clumsy English =)

Comment: have you tried to update google play services?

Comment: @anandwana yes, sure

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app's build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: @SlylySly check also your caldroidcustom and cheetah-mobile-3.4.7 modules